# Encapsulate the argument captured in (?P<topic_id>\d+) as request object's attribute

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

In the `urlpatterns` Django send a get request and and topic_id argument to views.py

```
url(r'^edit_topic/(?P<topic_id>\d+)$', views.edit_topic, name='edit_topic'),
```

In the views.py get passed in the two arguments

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Show a single topic and all its entries."""
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
```

I wonder if `topic_id` could be included in `request` and send single one argument to views.py

```
def topic(request):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=request.topic_id)
```

The codes will encounter error now,
but it's not difficult to achieve in the implement details of Django to   add 'topic_id' attribute to request object.
What's the disadvantage if package `topic_id` to the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it can be done but the urlpatterns need to be changed a bit.

```
url(r'^edit_topic/$', views.edit_topic, name='edit_topic'),
```

When you create your request as

```
<domain_name>/edit_topic?topic_id=<your_id>
```

For example, a request would look like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit_topic?topic_id=1000
```

In views.py when a request arrives you can do a GET operation in order to  get the value

```
def topic(request):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=request.GET('topic_id'))
```